Is there a function to select the first or second element of a pair?
I this wiki article about Kuratowski pair $p=(a,b)= \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \}$ we see
$$
\pi_1(p) = \bigcup\bigcap p = \bigcup \{x\} = x
$$
and similar for second element
$$
\pi_2(p) = ... = \bigcup \{y\} = y
$$
But isn't the use of the projection function notation $\pi_1(p)$ here misleading?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the projection function for the Kuratowski pair cannot exist under the ZFC
Proof
According to the simplest definition, a function is a set of pairs, i.e. $f= \{ (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), ... \}$
Therefore, the projection function $\pi_1$ (similarly $\pi_2$) is also a set of pairs. If the function $\pi_1$ exists, we can construct such a Kuratowski pair $b = (\pi_1,1)$. And now
$\pi_1(b) = \pi_1$
so it means that in function (set of pairs) $\pi_1 = \{ (p_1, a_1), (p_2, a_2), ....  \}$ there is following pair $(\pi_1, \pi_1)=\{ \{\pi_1\} \}$. So
$\{\{\pi_1\}\} \in \pi_1$
So this means that the set $\pi_1$ (i.e. the function) is a set that contains itself (at some level of nesting) - which seems to be impossible within ZFC. Therefore, the assumption that $\pi_1$ exists leads to a contradiction.
It seems that there is no function that allows to extract an element of a pair - at most we can say that there is some "procedure" that allows to get the first or second element
Is my reasoning correct?
Update 2024-07-30
I took the liberty of adding relevant information about $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ to the Wikipedia article.

Indeed, $\pi_1$ is not a function in ZFC. You can also prove it a simpler way: its domain would be the "set" of all pairs, which is obviously a proper class, not a set.

For a simpler example, consider the so called "successor function" $s(x) = x \cup {x}$ which is widely used in the theory of ordinal numbers. This is also not really a function in the sense of ZFC. And the same problem arise with the ordinal or cardinal "operations".

As you have noticed, notions like Kuratowski projection and the union "function" $x\mapsto \bigcup x$ are treated, in the metatheory, as (definable) classes that represent procedures. Kunen's famous Set Theory (2011) has elaborated on the topic of how to convert arguments involving the informal notion of classes into pure first-order deductions; see sections I.1 -- I.4.
To be more specific, let $\varphi(p,x)$ denote the formula
$$\forall w[w=x \leftrightarrow \exists u[\forall v\in p[u\in v]\wedge[x= u]]]$$
(or any definition of Kuratowski projection that you may find reasonable) of the language $\mathcal L=\lbrace \in\rbrace$. Let $F(f)$ denote
$$\exists x\exists y[\forall u\in f[u\in x\times y]\wedge \forall s\in x\exists!t\in y[(x,y)\in f]]$$
that says $f$ is a function. What you have established is
$$\mathrm{ZFC}+(\forall p\forall x(x=\pi_1(p) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x,y)))\vdash \neg\exists f\forall p\forall x[F(f)\wedge\pi_1(p)=x\leftrightarrow f(p)=x]$$
